# How do I remove specific byte sequences with sed and vim using hex addresses?

Tags: vim, sed, utf-8, bytecode

I've got a string, looks like this in vim

> PFLUGERVILLE  TX  7x691 227 12515 <83>¨¨ x Research Boulevard

For reference in vim,

> **ga** Print the ascii value of the character under the cursor in decimal, hexadecimal and octal.
>
> **g8** Print the hex values of the bytes used in the character under the cursor, assuming it is in UTF-8 encoding.  This also shows composing characters.  The value of 'maxcombine' doesn't matter.

I can inspect it if I go over it `<83>` and type `ga`, I get this

```
<<83>> 131, Hex 0083, Octal 203
```

If I type `g8`, I get

```
c2 83
```

I would have thought that

```
sed -e's/\x00\x83//g' ./file.csv
```

would work to remove the character, but no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not

```
sed -e's/\x00\x83//g' ./file.csv
```

but,

```
LC_CTYPE=C sed -e's/\x83//g' ./file.csv
```

You have to use `LC_CTYPE=C`, and remove the starting `\x00`.

Comment: Is this the answer? If so, please accept it so that other folks know. If it isn't, and it is further information about your question, please click `edit` under your question and add it in there and delete this.

Comment: I would accept it, I can't because of the 2 day limit.